# How to build project to one file setup?

Tags: winforms

How to build project to one file setup? 
I try some tool installshield and project for visual. but it build more one file.
Thanks for read.

Comment: Installshield can create a single msi file installer. In most cases just the msi file is sufficient. Delete the extra files. Check if "leave files uncompressed" is ticked.

Comment: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects)

Comment: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UnniRavindranathan-MSFT.MicrosoftVisualStudio2013InstallerProjects)

Comment: [How to: Create or Add a Setup Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c(v=vs.100).aspx)